# How use UIL with dropbox http api

Tags: android, dropbox, universal-image-loader

This is how a download works(https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http#documentation-files-download)

```
curl -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download 
  --header "Authorization: Bearer myToken" 
  --header "Dropbox-API-Arg: {\"path\": \"/Homework/math/Prime_Numbers.jpg\"}"
```

As you can see this way let you download different images with same url.

Should I create a new instance for loader every single image? Which it not seems possible because I don't know how many images will I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had realised that displayImage have an expected DisplayImageOptions parameter. So i created one with my custom parameters

```
DisplayImageOptions customOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        ...
        .extraForDownloader(headers)
        .build();
```

Then in loader ensuring path is different every time, I achieve it using `#`

```
path = path+"#"+my_unique_id;
loader.displayImage(path, view, defaultOptions, listener);
```